# Can I find a smooth function $f^+$ such that $f \leq f^+$ when $f \geq 0$ is non decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, approximation-theory

I am trying to conclude an $\varepsilon,\delta$ proof. I have a non-decreasing function $f(r) \geq 0$  that converges to $0$ when $r \to 0 $ $(r >0)$. I want to find a sequence $r_n$ such thant $n r_n^2 f(r_n) \to 0$ and $n r_n^2 \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$. When $f$ is smooth we can choose $r_n = \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{1/2}}$.

What about the general case ? My idea was to regularize $f$ by a function $f^+$ such that $f^+(r)$ converges to $0$ when $r \to 0$ and $f \leq f^+$.

Is it possible to do that ?

Thank you.

**Edit :**

If it can help, the function $f$ has the following expression :

$f(r) = \Bbb E\left(\sup\limits_{|h| \leq r} g(h)\right)$
where $g(h)$ is a positive random function that satisfies $g(h) \to 0$ when $h \to 0$ and $g(h) \leq g^+$ with $g^+$ integrable.

**Edit 2 :**

In fact we can't find in general such a $f^+$. Take $f(r) = \sqrt{r}$. Then $\frac{f(r)}{r} = \frac1{\sqrt{r}} \leq \frac{f^+(r) - f^+(0)}{r}$.

But, I can't prove or disprove my first question. It can be reformulated as : find a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \to \infty$ and $a_n f(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}) \to 0$.

I can prove it when $\limsup_{r \to 0} f(r)/r < \infty$. But, the example $f(r) = \sqrt{r}$ show that we should be able to find $a_n$ in a more general setting (indeed we can take $a_n = \ln(n)$).

Comment: I assume the domain of $f$ is the nonpositive real line? Otherwise $f$ non-increasing, non negative, $f(r)$ converging to $0$ as $r \rightarrow 0$ gives $f(r)=0$ for positive $r$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I edit the question.